# Hadoop Connection Refused in VMWare

Tags: hadoop, virtualbox, vmware, sandbox, connection-refused

I am trying to install Sandbox Hadoop in VMWare but getting error as below.

safemode: call from sandbox.hortonworks.com/10.0.0.17 to sandbox.hortonworks.com/8020 failed on connection exception : java.net.ConnectException : Connection Refused

Getting the same error when I try to install Hadopp for VirtualBox in oracle virtual box.

Found one workaround of changing network setting from NAT to bridge in VMWare or VirtualBox but that also does not work.